# config.rb http images path only gives one slash?

Tags: image, sass, config

I'm particularly new with SASS for developing a Wordpress site. Problem occured when I need to create a http:// path using config.rb following settings:

```
http_path = "/"
css_dir = '/'
sass_dir = '_/components/sass'
javascripts_dir = '_/js'
images_dir = 'http://localhost:8888/acdbox/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/'

fonts_dir = '_/fonts'
output_style = :extended

relative_assets = true
disable_warnings = true
```

It outputs as:

```
 background: url('http:/localhost:8888/acdbox/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/home-order-bg2.png')
```

Missing the http double slash (http://) and only displays as (http:/) single slash. Am I doing anything wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do it but it works. By setting up http_images_path to where the image exactly placed and relative_assets to false

```
http_path = "/"
http_images_path = "http://localhost:8888/acdbox/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/"
css_dir = '/'
sass_dir = '_/components/sass'
javascripts_dir = '_/js'
images_dir = ''

fonts_dir = '_/fonts'
output_style = :expanded

relative_assets = false
disable_warnings = true
```

Is this the right approach? Is there any better way of doing this?